# JTextArea: How to append string to JTextArea from another class

Tags: java, string, jtextarea

I have a simple GUI which has a `JTextArea`. I have created a method to get a message from the user and another to append text to the text area as follows

```
Message m = new Message();

...

private void messageBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {   
     m.getMessage();
}

public void printOnTextArea(String text){
    jTextArea.append(text);
}
```

I am calling this method from my `Message.java` class like so

```
SimpleGUI simpleGUI = new SimpleGUI():

...

public void getMessage(){
    String message = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter message");
    printMessage(message);
}

public void printMessage (String message){
    simpleGUI.printOnTextArea(message);
}
```

But even though the message entered to the JOptionPane is being passed to the `printOnTextArea()` correctly, it is not appearing on the JTextArea, does anybody see what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Please post some code that we can try. Otherwise, the above looks ok.

Comment: Well thats pretty much the code, just created a simple version first to test and running into this problem. This thing is, the string is being passes to the correct method so i really do not understand why it is not working because if i call the printOnTextArea() method from the GUI class it prints it out, it just does not work if i call it from my Message.java class

Comment: Just post a runnable code. The issue may be obvious with the complete code while now it is obvious to me that it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Ive found months ago this TextAreaWriter .. it could be helpful i think

http://pastebin.com/THGccgGu

Its for SWT but should work with awt too